# How to make a python source code edit it self

Tags: python

I am writing a program about countries around the world.

I want to add the feature for the user to add his own country, modifying the source code.

This is the current source code written in Python 3.0.1:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "Bem Vindo a um programa educativo sobre os variados paises do Mundo, creado por Tomas Simoes, 2015"
contry = raw_input("Qual e o pais que desejas visitar? - ")

if contry == "Afeganistao":
    print "O que desejas saber sobre o/a", contry,"?"
    print "1 - Cultura"
    print "2 - Linguagem"
    print "3 - Historia"
    print "4 - Localizacao"
    contry_spec = raw_input(" : ")
    if contry_spec == "1":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a cultura do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "2":
        print "A linguagem do/a", contry,"e pachto e dari."
    elif contry_spec == "3":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a historia do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "4":
        print "O/A", contry,"faz fronteira com o Irao, o Turquemenistao, o Uzebequistao, o Tajiquistao, a China, e o Paquistao." 
elif contry == "Africa do Sul":
    print "O que desejas saber sobre o/a", contry,"?"
    print "1 - Cultura"
    print "2 - Linguagem"
    print "3 - Historia"
    print "4 - Localizacao"
    contry_spec = raw_input(" : ")
    if contry_spec == "1":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a cultura do/a", contry,"desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "2":
        print "A linguagem do/a", contry,"e incerta."
    elif contry_spec == "3":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a historia do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "4":
        print "O/A", contry,"faz fronteira com a Zamibia, o Botsuana, o Zimbabue, Monçambique, a Suazilandia e o Lesoto."
elif contry == "Akrotiri":
    print "O que desejas saber sobre o/a", contry,"?"
    print "1 - Cultura"
    print "2 - Linguagem"
    print "3 - Historia"
    print "4 - Localizacao"
    contry_spec = raw_input(" : ")
    if contry_spec == "1":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a cultura do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "2":
        print "A linguagem do/a", contry,"e ingles e grego."
    elif contry_spec == "3":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a historia do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "4":
        print "O/A", contry,"faz fronteira com nada."
elif contry == "Albania":
    print "O que desejas saber sobre o/a", contry,"?"
    print "1 - Cultura"
    print "2 - Linguagem"
    print "3 - Historia"
    print "4 - Localizacao"
    contry_spec = raw_input(" : ")
    if contry_spec == "1":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a cultura do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "2":
        print "A linguagem do/a", contry,"e Albanes."
    elif contry_spec == "3":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a historia do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "4":
        print "O/A", contry,"faz fronteira com Montenegro, Cosovo, a Servia, e a Grecia."
```

Each contry is composed by a simple section of if, elif sentences:

```
elif contry == "Africa do Sul":
    print "O que desejas saber sobre o/a", contry,"?"
    print "1 - Cultura"
    print "2 - Linguagem"
    print "3 - Historia"
    print "4 - Localizacao"
    contry_spec = raw_input(" : ")
    if contry_spec == "1":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a cultura do/a", contry,"desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "2":
        print "A linguagem do/a", contry,"e incerta."
    elif contry_spec == "3":
        print "Nao sei muito sobre a historia do/a", contry,",desculpa!"
    elif contry_spec == "4":
        print "O/A", contry,"faz fronteira com a Zamibia, o Botsuana, o Zimbabue, Monçambique, a Suazilandia e o Lesoto."
```

I want to know how, when the user types "Add", and then types what I ask for example, name,how can the code add one of those segments to it self.

Comment: why not write the country data in a database? wouldn't that be the normal way to go? security-wise your approach may be fatal...

Comment: You want a *database* to store the data and immutable *source code* to read from and modify that database! Self-modifying source code is a terrible idea. The database can be something as simple as a file, SQLite database, or some full-blown database server.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to store data *in the source code*?

Comment: You want a function call to modify the source? I don't know if this is possible but it seems very ill advised. Your else ifs print out a one of five attributes about a country. Have the user create a new object instead.

Comment: It's possible, but it's difficult and in almost all cases a bad idea. Use some other means of persistence instead, fx `pickle`.

Comment: How would i use a database in my current code then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the source code, is probably a bad idea I would advise that you save the data in a datafile, like a .csv file. You can if you really wanted, create new files in your current directory like this

```
import os
newFileName = os.getcwd() + '/' + "pythonfile" + '.py'
newFob = open(newFileName, 'w')
```

and when ever you are ready to write something

```
newFob.write("something")
```

and then newFob.close() when the file is done.